# How not to take into account (in a filter statement) a missing argument in a function R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to filter a dataset in a function.
I would like to filter this dataset only taking into account the arguments that are passed in the function, omitting the one that are missing

I've tried with the match.call() - do.call() process, but it doesn't work and I think I'm using it wrongly. Could someone help me with my issue?

```
people = data.frame(SEX = c("F", "H", "F", "F"),
           ADULT = c(1,1,1,0))

f = function(dataset, sex = NULL, adult = NULL){
  data <- dataset%>%filter(SEX == sex & ADULT == adult)
  return(data)}

f(dataset = people, sex = "F", adult = 1)


g = function(dataset, sex, age){

argList <-  as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)[-1])
# Enforce inclusion of non-optional arguments
argList$dataset <- dataset
do.call(f,argList)}

g(dataset = people, sex = "F")
```

The output of the calling of function f is :

```
  SEX ADULT
1   F     1
2   F     1
```

This is what I want. But I would like the output of `f(dataset = people, sex = "F")` to be :

```
  SEX ADULT
1   F     1
2   F     1
3   F     0
```

Comment: You are likely looking for the `missing` function in R. It will return `TRUE` if an argument is missing, and false otherwise.

Comment: Actually, this is an example of my function in which I have much more than 3 arguments. So, I prefer not to use the missing function because this would imply testing if it's missing for a lot of arguments.

Comment: The problem is - as shown by @nicola 's answer, that you are specifying the arguments as "NULL" - filter doesn't work on "NULL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
f <- function(dataset, sex = NULL, adult = NULL){
  cond1 <- if (!is.null(sex)) quote(SEX==sex) else TRUE
  cond2 <- if (!is.null(adult)) quote(ADULT==adult) else TRUE
  data <- dataset %>% filter(!!(cond1) & !!(cond2))
  return(data)
}
```

Comment: An explanation might help the OP.

Comment: dplyr supports tidyeval … in other words, use `!! cond` instead of `eval(cond)`.

Comment: @LucileRainteau Glad it helped. You can upvote/accept the answer, if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Although a little bit more verbose, you could do the following:

```
people <- data.frame(SEX = c("F", "H", "F", "F"),
       ADULT = c(1,1,1,0))

f <- function(dataset, sex = "NULL", adult = "NULL")
{
if(sex != "NULL"){ data <- dataset%>%filter(SEX == sex)}
if(adult != "NULL"){ data <- dataset%>%filter(ADULT == adult)}
return(data)
}

f(people, sex = "F")
```

The output would be:

```
   SEX ADULT
1   F     1
2   F     1
3   F     0
```